# How can I avoid making another network request with fetching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, fetch

I have created an API with express. I am fetching API request in client-side with React. How can I avoid making a network request every time the page mounts? I would like to store the fetch request and use it again when the page mounts rather than making another network request.

The data from API request are very large array, over 45,000 entries.

```
// Core
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

// Components
import SearchStock from '../../components/search-stock';

const Home = () => {
    const [searchStocks, setSearchStock] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const requestOne = axios
            .get('/api/exchange/us')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.data.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Error with API request
                console.log('error', error);
            });

        const requestTwo = axios
            .get('/api/exchange/to')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.data.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Error with API request
                console.log('error', error);
            });

        Promise.all([requestOne, requestTwo])
            .then((values) => {
                if (values[0] && values[1]) {
                    setSearchStock([...values[0], ...values[1]]);
                } else {
                    console.log('CHECK with API for US and TO Exchange!');
                }

                setLoading(true);
            })

            .catch((error) => {
                // Error with API request
                setLoading(true);
                console.log('error', error);
            });

    return (
        <div>
            {!isLoading ? (
                <p>Fetching data...</p>
            ) : (
                <div>{searchStocks && <SearchStock data={searchStocks} />}</div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Axios has some additional extensions one of which is a [cache adapter](https://github.com/kuitos/axios-extensions/blob/master/README.md#cacheadapterenhancer). You may want to check it out.

Comment: do you mean also such actions like page reload(F5)? or just for in-app navigation(say using `react-router`)?

Comment: This is a single page application and using reach router. @skyboyer